# Объединение репозиториев svn в git

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

Мигрирую с `svn` в `git`. Возникла необходимость объеднить два каталога принадлежащие одному репозиторию из `svn` в один депозитарий  в `git` с сохранением истории изменений файлов в обоих каталогах.
Каталоги лежат в разных директориях.
Как можно решить данную ситуацию???

Импорт делала с помощью git clone Svn.но похоже это не то что мне нужно. Думаю попробовать следующее:

- создать репозиторий А в гит и перенести туда каталог_1 из svn.
- создать репозиторий B в гит и перенести туда каталог_2 из svn.
- Сделать клон репозитория А на локальную машину.
- у репозитория A поменять remote, указать репозиторий B  и сделать pull.
- у репозитория A поменять remote обратно и сделать push.

Технические подробности:

Пользуюсь TortoiseGit и SourceTree. Импорт делаю с помощью `git clone` Svn.Submodule не рассматриваю, ведь по сути все равно два репозитория в гите будет для каждого каталога svn. Ну вот и интересно , как объединить два каталога svn которые лежат в разных директориях одного репозитория так что бы история изменений и того и другого каталога осталась. Импорт корневой директории не рассматривается.

Comment: Да, такое возможно - но устроит ли вас такой ответ? Неужели вы хотели узнать только это?

Comment: сформулируйте, пожалуйста, вопрос по-другому. иначе на него может быть только один, абсолютно логичный ответ, который уже приведён комментарием выше. и добавьте, пожалуйста, больше конкретики: каким средством импорта вы пользуетесь, с какими трудностями при этом столкнулись, подойдут ли вам `git submodules`, и, если нет, в каком виде вы хотите объединить две истории изменений из двух разных репозиториев. отредактировать вопрос можно, нажав кнопку [edit].

Comment: Если полученный ответ вас устроил, вы можете его принять (галочка рядом с ответом). Если нет — задавайте уточняющие вопросы в комментариях.

Answer (score 1):

Чуть более прямых решений как минимум два:

- клонировать начиная c common parent этих двух директорий, исключив все лишнее с `--ignore-paths=<regex>`
- начать с init, руками исправить `[svn-remote]` секцию в конфиге, прописав нужные 2 пути в branch или fetch ключи